# Disable signature field in pdf using c#

Tags: c#-4.0, pdf, itext

i am creating a pdf tablet application in that according to the users login. Signature field should be visible. for example,if student login to pdf application,student signature field should be visible(can edit) to him.Staff signature field should be disable(cant edit).According to the users login i need to read the signature field.

thanks in advance

pl help me

Comment: The question is very unclear. You've used the iTextSharp tag, but your question seems to be about viewing a PDF. You're saying a staff signature field should be disabled, but you're not saying if that field already contains a signature. Also: have you checked ISO-32000-1 to find out if what you're asking for is even possible? I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: Hi Bruno Thanks for replying.. yes you are correct.there will be two signature field (staff) and (student). By default both the signature field does not contains signature. i(staff) am viewing the pdf at that student signature field should be disabled.Staff cannot access that student signature field is that possible??

Comment: Because before anything is signed, any change can be applied (such as enabling a disabled field). However: after the first signature is applied, you should be very careful applying any change. Enabling the disabled field may be possible, but it may also break the first signature, depending on the nature of the first signature. I'd drop this requirement as it's asking for problems. Surely you don't want the second signature to break the first one? If you're willing to take that risk, make sure the first signature is applied using the correct DMP settings.

Comment: i understand bruno but i am going to sign only one signature in an enabling field .i will not overwrite any signature .please put some reference or some sample code for disabling signature field.

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf